# How to raise a custom Exception in Rails 3+ with normal control flow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following controller method:

```
  def create
    @client = User.find(params[:client][:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @client.present? && @client.add_manager(current_user)
        format.html { redirect_to clients_path, notice: "Successfully added manager" }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to clients_path, error: "Could not find client" }
      end
    end
  end
```

How do I get this to fail properly in the else block instead of throwing a RuntimeError which turns into a "Something went wrong" on production?

```
  def add_manager(user)
    raise "Already a manager" if self.manager_users.include?(user)
    self.manager_users << user if user.trainer?
  end
```

Is the code...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

In your controller

```
class YourAppName::AlreadyManagerError < StandardError

end
```

Now change "Already a manager" to the name of your custom error

```
def add_manager(user)
  raise YourAppName::AlreadyManagerError if self.manager_users.include?(user)
  self.manager_users << user if user.trainer?
end
```

Then in your ApplicationController

```
rescue_from YourAppName::AlreadyManagerError do |exception|
  render :nothing => "Already a manager", :status => 404
end
```

This [article](https://ariejan.net/2011/10/14/rails-3-customized-exception-handling/) goes into more detail. Also check out [rescue_from](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods/rescue_from)

Comment: How do rails control flows like a respond to block with if and then #save on that record cause it to hit the true if block and then false for the redirect? I just want to follow the same pattern with my own method.